# How to include text intended only for reviewers in main manuscript submission?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

When I submit papers using blind review, I sometimes need to include text to reviewers that is not intended for the actual publication.

For example,

- Sometimes I include a URL to the OSF that has all the materials and data for the project. However, because the paper is blind review, the url is not yet active. Instead I include a special blind review URL with comments along the lines of "while this paper is under peer review, an version of the repository without author names can be accessed at ....". I often place this in a footnote.
- Other times I might want to put a black mark through something identifying like the institution that approved the ethics of the study, because this might give away my identity. And I might want to include some text to the reviewers explaining why this was blacked out.

However, I often find that these kind of notes to reviewers end up in the proofs. Of course, at that stage, I can just ask the the people doing the proofs to remove this. But I think it would be better if I didn't have to do that, and I didn't have to worry about whether they would make the change correctly.

So, the question:

**How do you include text in a journal submission manuscript that you want the reviewers to read, but that you don't want to appear in the main publication?**

I've tried using footnotes and that didn't work. I thought maybe putting such text in a textbox with some special words might help.
Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: What about including your comments in the cover letter to the editor, and asking that they be passed along to the reviewers?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the suggestion. That sounds like a burden for the editor, and something that would not map well onto standardized review processes.

Comment: Maybe your real problem is poor copyediting.  Not much you can do about that, except maybe try a different publisher.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Perhaps. I'd probably frame it as a minor annoyance. i.e., nothing too serious; it would just be nice to have a trick for preventing having to pick it up at the proof stage each time

Comment: If you're a reviewer for this journal, how do other authors handle this? If you aren't, or if what you're trying to do is so unusual that the journal might not have a workflow for it, maybe shoot an editor an email and ask how they prefer you to handle it. (Answers here can give ideas, but might not work for all journal workflows, so this might be a good thing to do regardless.)

Comment: Another thought is to collect all of these notes on a separate page appended to the manuscript.  Then it should be obvious to the copy editor to omit it; they don't have to hunt through the whole document at all.

Comment: Things like this are why I detest double-blind peer review!!

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned the *online e-companion* approach which works well in some situations.

Another I've used is adding an **Appendix** to the paper so it is organically included in the initial submission only. We explicitly label it for the reviewers' convenience only and that it will be removed from the final version. After the first round of reviews, we typically remove it and place as an appendix in our [Response to Reviewers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72005/how-to-respond-to-peer-review-a-step-by-step-guide-to-my-first-response/116160#116160). This has been convenient for us as authors and for the editor. It may not work for all situations.